# Правильная установка пакета nuget C#

Tags: c#, библиотеки, nuget

Здравствуйте. Нашел на NuGet бета-версию [библиотеки](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apix.Sync.Kinopoisk.Client/1.0.0-beta-000014) для kinopoisk. Только вот установить ее не получается из-за ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можете подсказать что я делаю не так? NuGet начал пользоваться совсем недавно, поэтому всех особенностей еще не знаю. Если что, то сборки из пункт "Dependencies" пытался установить. `NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)` удалось поставить, а вот `Apix.Http.Client (>= 1.0.0-beta-009)` нет, т.к. все такая же ошибка появлялась.

Comment: @Igor делал это, не помогло. Понижал вплоть до 4.0

Answer (score 5):

Библиотека написана под `.NETStandard 1.6`, для совместимости у вас должен быть установлен `.NET Framework 4.6.3`.

Подробнее о `.NET Standard` можно прочесть на странице [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/standard/library).

Там же можно найти полную таблицу поддержки для различных платформ.

Comment: А где найти 4.6.3? Я только 4.6.2 нашел

Comment: @АндрейФедоров пока еще его нет, поэтому кое-где пишут `vNext`

Comment: получается, я не смогу установить данную библиотеку?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров да, _на данный момент_ не сможете